# Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug' Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, compiler-errors, flutter-dependencies

I was trying to run my Flutter code and this error shows up:
[enter link description here](https://easyupload.io/hr9gh6)

Here's my Flutter doctor:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ZKUf.png)

**I found some solutions on the net but it isn't working for me, things which i've tried:

1. Deleting pubspec.lock, and running Pub.get in pubspec.yaml
2. Running 'Flutter clean' and doing pub.get **

Comment: Hi! Please add error output  and flutter doctor  output to your answer as text

Comment: @Mol0ko flutter doctor output:
C:\Users\dassa>flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19043.1110], locale en-US)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Android Studio
[√] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2021.1)
[√] Connected device (2 available)

• No issues found!

Comment: @Mol0ko and for error output, it's too big to paste to here, I can mail you though if it's okay with you.

Comment: there is no need to mail me. Anyway you'd better to update your question with error and flutter doctor output. Here you will find all reasons why https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/10595176